# Run Firefox or Chrome with disabled SSO feature

Tags: windows, browser, webmail

I have configured in my environment SSO to webmail so this works on Iexplorer, Chrome and Firefox, but I would to run ocassionally one of these browser (or other) with SSO feature disable and allow me to login with different login password to webmail. How to do that?

Comment: What is SSO? What did you do to configure that thing? Is that Internet Explorer?

Comment: I mean Single Sign On, to my webmail zimbra client, I configured it using GPO (settings like Internet Explorer Intranet Zones, autologon in intranet etc) For firefox I configured parameters like :network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris and
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris